# Typescript exporting and reexporting interface and other data

Tags: typescript, import, export

I am new to typescript. How can I export typedefinitions (classes, interfaces) + all variables from specific file? I tried this:

models.ts

```
export interface CounterState {
    count: number;
}

let t = 5;
export {t};
```

index.ts

```
import * as models from './models';
models.t -> ok
models.CounterState -> not visible, why?
export default  { models };
```

reducer.ts

```
import CounterStore from "./index";


CounterStore.models.t -> ok
CounterStore.models.CounterState -> not visible, why?
```

Why * is not importing everything? 
If I do it this way: `import {CounterState} from "./models";`it will work.

edit: If I change interface to class it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with import/export but with the fact that you are **trying to evaluate an interface**, which is not possible:

- the actual interface declaration does not compile to any javascript, so trying to call `models.CounterState` has no meaning in the compiled js.
- if you declare a class however, you do have a compiled result. This explains why this will not throw an error.

I just want to give another shout-out to the extreme obscurity of typescript errors.

For the difference between the two, have a look at the [equivalent playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ICounter%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20No%20compilation%20result%0A%09count%3A%20number%20%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Counter%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20has%20actual%20compilation%20result%0A%09count%3A%20number%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20interfaceImplemenetation%3A%20ICounter%20%2F%2F%20Compiles%20fine%0ACounter%20%2F%2F%20Compiles%20fine%0AICounter%20%2F%2F%20Compiles%20to%20undefined) and what it compiles to:

```
interface ICounter { // No compilation result
  count: number 
}

class Counter { // has actual compilation result
  count: number
}

let interfaceImplemenetation: ICounter // Compiles fine
Counter // Compiles fine
ICounter // Compiles to undefined
```

Comment: thanks for clarification, http://jaysoo.ca/2016/02/28/organizing-redux-application/ -> how can I follow these rules in typescript? I mean creating index which holds everything for other modules?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean. If I'm creating redux applications, I often just put my state interface in a global declaration file somewhere in the root (eg. index.d.ts), then I don't have to import it everywhere ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. (if that's your question  )

Comment: yup but there is a state per reducer. I am not talking about global state but single reducer state and later when I combine them in global state I need to referenc eit

Comment: I don't think there is a best practice for this yet. I think it is pretty intuitive to declare the interface of a reducer state in the reducer file, and import all these when you're declaring your global state.